# TclError/Install error from Tcl

Tags: python, tcl, activetcl

I just got Tkinter work on my OSX 10.8.4 with Python 2.7.5 installed with Anaconda.
I can now import Tkinter with

```
import Tkinter
```

or

```
from Tkinter import *
```

and it seems to work (no error message).

Now I try to create a display. I do :

```
window = Tk()
```

and at this point I get :

```
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-711542866473> in <module>()
----> 1 fenetre = Tk()

/Users/geoffroysarrazin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.pyc in __init__(self, screenName, baseName, className, useTk, sync, use)
   1743                 baseName = baseName + ext
   1744         interactive = 0
-> 1745         self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
   1746         if useTk:
   1747             self._loadtk()

TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
/opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/lib/tcl8.5 
/Users/geoffroysarrazin/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/tcl8.5 
/Users/geoffroysarrazin/anaconda/python.app/lib/tcl8.5 
/Users/geoffroysarrazin/anaconda/python.app/Contents/library 
/Users/geoffroysarrazin/anaconda/python.app/library 
/Users/geoffroysarrazin/anaconda/python.app/tcl8.5.13/library 
/Users/geoffroysarrazin/anaconda/tcl8.5.13/library



This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

I tried to install ActiveTcl8.5.14.0 but no change. And I dont even know what this directory

```
/opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/lib/tcl8.5
```

actually is...

Comment: Very odd. (The “anaconda conga” is probably in an environment variable, probably `TCL_LIBRARY`, but that's likely being set somewhere inside Tkinter…)